# Subspaces if they don't intersect

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose I have a vector space $V$ and two subspaces $U, W$ and $\dim U = 3, \dim W = 2$ and $U, W$ do not share any vectors other than $\overrightarrow{0}$ then is the union of the bases of $U, W$ linearly independent in $V$?

I know that $U \subseteq V, W \subseteq V$ and that $U \cap W = \overrightarrow{0}$

It must be true then right?

Comment: And you know the definition of linearly independent so you can prove it using that.

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_3 x_3 + \beta_1 y_1 + \beta_2 y_2 = 0$, then $\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_3 x_3 = -\beta_1 y_1 - \beta_2 y_2 \in U \cap W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\}$ be a basis for $U$ and $\{y_{1}, y_{2}\}$ be a basis for $W$. Then consider $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} + b_{1}y_{1} + b_{2}y_{2} = 0$ for some constants.

If $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} + b_{1}y_{1} + b_{2}y_{2} = 0$ then $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} + b_{1}y_{1} + b_{2}y_{2} \in U \cap V$

We have $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} = -b_{1}y_{1} - b_{2}y_{2}$. But as $U \cap W = 0$, this implies that $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} = -b_{1}y_{1} - b_{2}y_{2} = 0$ (why?) and the only way that can happen is if all $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are $0$ as $\{x_{i}\}$ and $\{y_{i}\}$ are bases so they are linearly independent by definition.

Comment: They both must be equal to $0$ because if $a_1x_1 + .. = -b_1y_1 + .. $ then that means they are the inersection, so must be 0

Comment: Exactly, hope this all helps!